# Python create folders structure based on previous month

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and have very little understanding about it. 
I have a set of files in a folder that is updated on a monthly basis. I wanted to Copy those files from that folder after every month end to a different folder location and this destination folder should contain the month and year. In most cases, this will be the previous month.

Is this possible to do with Python?

Comment: first of all you have to slice you project to small part, each part can be done easily. Also if you share the code you have tried so far you would get your answer much faster. I'll do it part by part and share by you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`file2copy` would be list of files that are in you source directory `./folder`. then for `item` in source folder in for loop files would move to destination folder,`os.mkdir(path)` is for creating folder in desire path.

`now = dt.datetime.now()` would give you today date and `before = now-relativedelta(months=+1)` is for one month before

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

now = dt.datetime.now()
before = now-relativedelta(months=+1)

path='path to destination/folder/'+str(before.year)+str(before.month)
os.mkdir(path)

source='path to source/folder/'
file2copy = os.listdir(source)
print(file2copy)


for item in file2copy:
    shutil.copy(source+item, path)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. But I'm getting the below error after running the code


"
    from dateutil.relativedelta import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'

Comment: it might be not install on your machine. install dateutil by `pip install python-dateutil` command https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/

Comment: I install this. Thanks

Comment: I run the code. But I'm unable to see any results;
following is the code I ran as per your above comment

import os
import shutil
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

now = dt.datetime.now()
before = now-relativedelta(months=+1)

path='E:\Python test'+str(before.year)+str(before.month)
os.mkdir(path)

source='E:\\New folder (2)'
file2copy = os.listdir(source)
print(file2copy)

for item in file2copy:
    shutil.copy(source+item, path)

Comment: You have to edit code based on file locations on machine

Comment: I have edited the code. There are on;y two places that I need to added right? 

where I need to give the path and the source.

Comment: Yes source and path need to edit. Are you given any error?

Comment: This is working now. The folder has also created. But the files are not getting copied to that newly created folder.

Comment: if nothing move, it might be because of list of file not correctly created `print(file2copy)` is this list filled with file names?

Comment: yes..I can see the file names are printed below the code print(file2copy). But those files are not getting created in the new folder which was created by the name of previous month

Comment: you have to debug to check source and destination folder and file. there shouldn't be issue.wrong paths is the only possible issue